# Assign value from one dataframe to another based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1

```
Severity Key
S3        1
S2        1
S3        2
S2        2
S1        3
S1        1
S3        3
```

df2

```
S1  S2  S3  Key
10  20  30   1
20  40  60   2
30  60  90   3
```

Output df that I'm expecting

```
Severity Key value
S3        1   30
S2        1   20
S3        2   60
S2        2   40
S1        3   30
S1        1   10
S3        3   90
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)** after **[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)**:

```
df1.merge(df2.melt('Key',var_name='Severity'),on=['Severity','Key'])
```

---

Output:

```
  Severity  Key  value
0       S3    1     30
1       S2    1     20
2       S3    2     60
3       S2    2     40
4       S1    3     30
5       S1    1     10
6       S3    3     90
```

Comment: This isn't working for me... I'm getting an empty df

Comment: @GK21 works fine on the test dfs you provided for me, did you check on the test dfs?. May be you want to ceck if you have the same structure for the original dfs.

Comment: sorry there was an issue with one of the column names... its working perfectly now. thanks

Comment: if there are keys in df1 (4 & 5 for example) that aren't present in df2 then those rows are excluded from output df. Is there any way to have those as well

Comment: @GK21 then just put `how='left'` in the merge. `df1.merge(df2.melt('Key',var_name='Severity'),on=['Severity','Key'],how='left')`